# How to convert tableau representation of random clifford gate into its matrix representation using stim?

Tags: entanglement, quantum-operation, clifford-group, stim, randomised-benchmarking

I am currently trying to benchmark my code with a Haar circuit and I require to sample clifford gates in matrix form. I know a function "stim.Tableau.random(n)" which does that and gives me the tableau representation.
Can I obtain the corresponding matrix form of the clifford unitary gate? Qiskit allows me to do it using the function

circuit = qiskit.quantum_info.random_clifford(n)

qiskit.circuit.Gate.to_matrix(circuit)

Is there any function available in stim which does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Stim v1.9+ you can get the unitary matrix of a tableau by calling [`stim.Tableau.to_unitary_matrix`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.Tableau.to_unitary_matrix).

---

*(Old answer from before v1.9)*

Stim v1.8 doesn't have a method to do this, but you can get around that by using the state channel duality and the tableau simulator's state_vector method. Note that, once you get past 8 qubit tableaus, this starts to take multiple seconds to finish.

```
import stim
import numpy as np


def tableau_to_unitary(tableau: stim.Tableau,
                       *,
                       canonical_global_phase: bool,
                       endian: str) -> np.ndarray:
    assert endian in ['little', 'big']
    sim = stim.TableauSimulator()
    n = len(tableau)

    # Create n Bell pairs.
    for q in range(n):
        sim.h(q)
        sim.cnot(q, q + n)

    # Take one qubit from each Bell pair, and apply the custom tableau to those qubits.
    # Operating on [0,n) instead of [n,2n) gets transposed unitaries (Y rotations are backwards).
    # Reversing the order switches the endian-ness.
    qubits = range(n, 2*n)
    if endian == 'big':
        qubits = qubits[::-1]
    state = sim.current_inverse_tableau()
    state.prepend(tableau**-1, qubits)
    sim.set_inverse_tableau(state)

    # Get the state and interpret it as a matrix via the state channel duality.
    result = sim.state_vector().reshape((2**n, 2**n)) * 2**(n/2)
    if canonical_global_phase:
        result = with_canonical_global_phase(result)
    return result


def with_canonical_global_phase(u: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    f = u.flat
    best_index = 0
    best_val = abs(f[0])
    for i in range(1, len(f)):
        v = abs(f[i])
        if v > best_val * 2:
            best_index = i
            best_val = v

    v = f[best_index]
    assert v != 0
    v /= abs(v)
    return u * (np.conj(v) / abs(v))
```

Testing that it works:

```
sqrt_y = tableau_to_unitary(stim.Tableau.from_conjugated_generators(
    xs=[
        stim.PauliString("-Z"),
    ],
    zs=[
        stim.PauliString("X"),
    ],
), canonical_global_phase=True, endian='big')
np.testing.assert_allclose(
    sqrt_y,
    np.array([
        [1, -1],
        [1, 1],
    ]) / np.sqrt(2),
    atol=1e-6,
)


sim = stim.TableauSimulator()
sim.x(0)
sim.h(1)
x_tensor_h = tableau_to_unitary(sim.current_inverse_tableau()**-1,
                                canonical_global_phase=True,
                                endian='big')
np.testing.assert_allclose(
    x_tensor_h,
    np.array([
        [0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, -1],
        [1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, -1, 0, 0],
    ]) / np.sqrt(2),
    atol=1e-6,
)

cnot = tableau_to_unitary(stim.Tableau.from_conjugated_generators(
    xs=[
        stim.PauliString("XX"),
        stim.PauliString("_X"),
    ],
    zs=[
        stim.PauliString("Z_"),
        stim.PauliString("ZZ"),
    ],
), canonical_global_phase=True, endian='big')

iswap = tableau_to_unitary(stim.Tableau.from_conjugated_generators(
    xs=[
        stim.PauliString("ZY"),
        stim.PauliString("YZ"),
    ],
    zs=[
        stim.PauliString("_Z"),
        stim.PauliString("Z_"),
    ],
), canonical_global_phase=True, endian='big')

s = tableau_to_unitary(stim.Tableau.from_conjugated_generators(
    xs=[
        stim.PauliString("Y"),
    ],
    zs=[
        stim.PauliString("Z"),
    ],
), canonical_global_phase=True, endian='big')
s_dag = tableau_to_unitary(stim.Tableau.from_conjugated_generators(
    xs=[
        stim.PauliString("-Y"),
    ],
    zs=[
        stim.PauliString("Z"),
    ],
), canonical_global_phase=True, endian='big')

np.testing.assert_allclose(
    cnot,
    np.array([
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
    ]),
    atol=1e-6,
)

np.testing.assert_allclose(
    iswap,
    np.array([
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1j, 0],
        [0, 1j, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
    ]),
    atol=1e-6,
)
np.testing.assert_allclose(s, np.diag([1, 1j]), atol=1e-6)
np.testing.assert_allclose(s_dag, np.diag([1, -1j]), atol=1e-6)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. The code is really helpful and works for me in sampling Clifford unitary in their expected matrix form. I only require it for small number of qubits in order to benchmark it with Haar code. I am also curious to know if their is any additional function which can perform single qubit measurement on a state and return a fixed state(say up spin) as an outcome? which is to similar to performing post selection.

Comment: @user21113 You can use `stim.TableauSimulator.measure_kickback` to get postselection-like effects, because it tells you how to get to the other post-measurement state.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the pseudo post measurement scheme and for all your answers regarding stim. If I may ask, Is their any way to reverse the output state vector of a tableau simulator from its default little endian to big endian order?

Comment: I found the answer in stim latest version after installing "pip install stim~=1.9.dev".